# Deleting rows from table specified by selection from same and other table (inner join)

Tags: mysql, sql-delete

I need to delete some rows from my DB, which I've selected with a selection sql statement

I've tried using aliases, but they also did not work

```sql
DELETE FROM OBSERVATION WHERE OBSERVATION.ID in
(SELECT OBSERVATION.ID from OBSERVATION
inner join SPECIMEN on SPECIMEN.ID=OBSERVATION.SPECIMEN_ID
WHERE SPECIMEN.GENDER="male"and OBSERVATION.VALUE_TERM is not null and OBSERVATION.PARAMETER_STABLE_ID="IMPC_PAT_028_002")
```

I always get the error:

> Error in query (1093): You can't specify target table 'OBSERVATION' for update in FROM clause

Comment: !?! Surely 'id' is a PRIMARY KEY !?!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `OBSERVATION` table in the `DELETE` and sub query, so you can use table alias name and mention it properly on the DELETE statement.

The following query will work in your scenario:

```
DELETE OB
FROM OBSERVATION OB
WHERE OB.ID IN (
    SELECT SOB.ID 
    FROM OBSERVATION SOB
    INNER JOIN SPECIMEN SP ON SP.ID = SOB.SPECIMEN_ID
    WHERE SP.GENDER = "male" AND 
          SOB.VALUE_TERM IS NOT NULL AND 
          SOB.PARAMETER_STABLE_ID = "IMPC_PAT_028_002"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Mysql don't allow a delete form the same table used  for select the rows  to delete  for avoid this you must buil a set of rows  not related to the original table

You could use a inner join on a subquery instead of in clause
this should be enough

```
DELETE 
FROM OBSERVATION 
INNER JOIN  (
    SELECT OBSERVATION.ID 
    from OBSERVATION
    inner join SPECIMEN on SPECIMEN.ID=OBSERVATION.SPECIMEN_ID
    WHERE SPECIMEN.GENDER="male"
    and OBSERVATION.VALUE_TERM is not null
     and OBSERVATION.PARAMETER_STABLE_ID="IMPC_PAT_028_002"
)  t  OBSERVATION.ID = t.ID
```

otherwise you need  to enforce   this way

```
DELETE 
FROM OBSERVATION 
INNER JOIN  (
  select id from( 
    SELECT OBSERVATION.ID 
    from OBSERVATION
    inner join SPECIMEN on SPECIMEN.ID=OBSERVATION.SPECIMEN_ID
    WHERE SPECIMEN.GENDER="male"
    and OBSERVATION.VALUE_TERM is not null
     and OBSERVATION.PARAMETER_STABLE_ID="IMPC_PAT_028_002"

     ) t1
)  t  OBSERVATION.ID = t.ID
```

Comment: ...or not bother with the temporary table

Answer (score 0):

On the assumption that observation.id is a PRIMARY KEY, why not use:

```
DELETE o
  FROM observation o
  JOIN specimen s
    ON s.id = o.specimen_id
 WHERE s.gender = 'male' 
   AND o.value_term IS NOT NULL 
   AND o.parameter_stable_id = 'IMPC_PAT_028_002'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE targetTable
FROM targetTable
INNER JOIN otherTable
    ON targetTable.col = otherTable.col
WHERE otherTable.col2 = “foo”
```